# How to find center of a conic section from the equation?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, plane-curves

If we are given a curve in the form
$$ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dx+2ey+f=0$$
and the following determinant
$$\delta=\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{vmatrix}=ac-b^2$$
is non-zero, then this is either a curve of elliptic type (an ellipse, a point or an empty set/an imaginary ellipse) or a curve of hyperbolic type (a hyperbola or a pair of lines). So in these cases in makes sense to talk about center of the curve, i.e., the point with respect to which this curve is symmetric.

The center can be found as the solution of the following system of equations
$$\begin{align*}
ax+by+d&=0,\\
bx+cy+e&=0.
\end{align*}$$
(This system has a unique solution, since the determinant of the matrix of this system is $\delta\ne0$.)

That means, the coordinates of the center can be computed as
$$\begin{align*}
x&=\frac{be-cd}\delta,\\
y&=\frac{bd-ae}\delta.
\end{align*}$$

Several resources can be found where this way of finding center is described. (Often in the form of solving $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} =0$, where $F(x,y)=ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dx+2ey+f$.)

> How can these conditions for the center be derived? How can we show that the point fulfilling these equation indeed is the center of the conic section?

Comment: I should say that I am aware of some derivations of these equations and some arguments why they work. However, I thought it might be good asking this question here to get some other perspective from answers of other users. And I also think this question might be useful for other users.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941210/why-does-partial-differentiation-give-centre-of-a-conic

Comment: Under the alternative definition of the conic centre as the point which bisects all the chords passing through it, how can we include a degenerate hyperbola in this, [as seen here](https://imgur.com/a/Dlckn8G), considering the chord AB, AO and BO aren't equal? Also, while the centre of a point ellipse can be defined to be that point itself, how can we use an empty-set ellipse in our treatment, as there seems to be no way to apply this to that case?

Comment: @harry I do not know the answer. (Well, it's not completely clear to me what is actually the question.) In any case, it seems that this might be something which could be posted as a separate question rather than a comment.

Comment: I solved one of my earlier doubts and have edited the question accordingly; the issue was that [an empty set has the determinant $\delta=0$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections#Classification) and therefore  can't be included in the consideration. Hope that's correct.

Comment: The other problem is this: the centre of a conic section is commonly defined as the point which bisects all the chords passing through it. For example, as in [this page from Loney's *Elements of Coordinate Geometry*](https://imgur.com/a/c5slkuQ). However, as per this definition, the centre seems not to be well-defined for degenerate hyperbolas, since as seen in [this example](https://imgur.com/a/Dlckn8G), the "centre" O does not bisect the chord AB.

Comment: The point of intersection of lines can still be arrived at as a "centre" using the methods in the answers, as it satisfies properties an actual center should satisfy, but I still don't think we can rigorously call *it* the centre.

Comment: @harry For example, if you take $x^2+y^2+1=0$, then $\delta=1$ and you have no real solutions. (The Wikipedia article you linked uses the wording "imaginary ellipse".) I have edited the question to include this case.

Answer (score 12):

**Matrix derivation**

The original equation can be described in a more concise form as 
$$\vec x A \vec x^T + \vec x \vec b^T + \vec b \vec x^T + f =0$$
or 
$$\vec x A \vec x^T + 2\vec x \vec b^T + f =0$$
where $\vec b=(d,e)$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{pmatrix}$.

If the vector $\vec x_0$ represents the center then in a coordinate system with the origin in this point the equation will be 
$$(\vec x-\vec x_0) A (\vec x-\vec x_0)^T + g =0$$
which can be rewritten as
$$\vec x A \vec x^T - 2\vec x A\vec x_0^T + \vec x_0 A \vec x_0^T +g.$$

Which means the we need to choose $\vec x_0$ in such way that $-2A\vec x_0^T=2\vec b^T$, i.e. $$A\vec x_0^T=-\vec b^T,$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}d\\e\end{pmatrix}.$$

This is precisely the following system of linear equations written in the matrix form:
$$
\begin{align*}
ax + by &= -d\\
bx + cy &= -e
\end{align*}
$$

(To give credit where credit is due, I was shown this derivation by a colleague of mine who taught labs for the same subject as I did, but with another group of students.)

---

**Derivatives**

We can view the curve as a level set of the function 
$$F(x,y)=ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dx+2ey.$$
The level sets of this function create the family of curves $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dx+2ey+f=0$, where the parameter $f$ is changing.

For example, if $\delta>0$ we get concentric ellipses, like in this example - the plots are taken from [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2%2B2xy%2B3y%5E2%2Bx%2By):

[image: Paraboloid]

[image: concentric ellipses]

And a [different plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%5Bx%5E2%2B2xy%2B3y%5E2%2Bx%2By%3D0%2C+x%5E2%2B2xy%2B3y%5E2%2Bx%2By%3D1%2C+x%5E2%2B2xy%2B3y%5E2%2Bx%2By%3D2%2C+x%5E2%2B2xy%2B3y%5E2%2Bx%2By%3D3%5D+x+from+-3+to+3+y+from+-2+to+2):

[image: Family of ellipses]

If $\delta>0$, we get a family of hyperbolas. [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2%2B2xy-3y%5E2%2Bx-y):

[image: Hyperboloid]

[image: Hyperbolas as the level sets]

And a [different plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%5Bx%5E2%2B2xy-3y%5E2%2Bx-y%3D-4%2C+x%5E2%2B2xy-3y%5E2%2Bx-y%3D-2%2C+x%5E2%2B2xy-3y%5E2%2Bx-y%3D0%2C+x%5E2%2B2xy-3y%5E2%2Bx-y%3D2%2C+x%5E2%2B2xy-3y%5E2%2Bx-y%3D4%5D):

[image: Family of hyperbolas]

In the first case, the function $F$ has minimum at the center of each of the ellipse. In the second case there is a saddle point. In both cases, the center fulfills
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} =0$$
which leads to the system of equations
\begin{align*}
ax + by +d&= 0\\
bx + cy +e&= 0
\end{align*}
which is precisely the linear system described above.

So far we have only drawn some pictures (which is good for intuition, but picture is not a proof.) If we want to give a more rigorous reason why this works we can use some known facts about quadratic forms.
We know from [Principal axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem) that there is a rotation and translation such that in the new coordinates the curve has 
$$\lambda_1 x^2 + \lambda_2 x^2=const$$
Clearly $F(x,y)=\lambda_1 x^2 + \lambda_2 x^2$ has partial derivatives equal to zero at the origin. (And depending on the signs of $\lambda_{1,2}$ we can say whether it has minimum, maximum or saddle point there.)

Comment: In addition, for $$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{pmatrix}$$  $\exists Q\in\text{Orth}$ s.t. $$Q^TAQ=\Lambda$$ which will transform the original equation into the most simple form $$\hat{a}\hat{x}^2+\hat{b}\hat{y}^2=\hat{c}$$

Comment: [relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941210/why-does-partial-differentiation-give-centre-of-a-conic)

Answer (score 7):

I would emphasize that a pure translation in the plane preserves the relationship between a figure and its center. Given
$$ A x^2 + 2 B xy + C y^2 + 2 D x + 2 E y + F = 0   $$
and solving for $(x_0, y_0)$ in
$$ A x_0 + B y_0 + D = 0, $$
$$ B x_0 + C y_0 + E = 0, $$
we introduce translated coordinates $(u,v)$ with
$$  x = u + x_0, $$
$$  y = v + y_0. $$
I'm not sure how much I will type in, but the original equation

$$ A x^2 + 2 B xy + C y^2 + 2 D x + 2 E y + F = 0   $$
becomes
$$ A u^2 + 2 B uv + C v^2 = \rm{constant.}   $$
Regardless of what type of figure this might be, it is centrally symmetric in $(u,v)$ coordinates: if $(u,v)$ is a solution, so is $(-u,-v).$

***APPENDIX:***

$$ A x^2 + 2 B xy + C y^2 + 2 D x + 2 E y + F = 0.   $$

$$ x = u + x_0 $$
$$ y = v + y_0 $$

$$  x^2 = u^2 + 2 x_0 u + x_0^2   $$
$$  xy = uv + y_0 u + x_0 v + x_0 y_0  $$
$$  y^2 = v^2 + 2 y_0 v + y_0^2  $$

$$  A x^2 + 2 B xy + C y^2 = (A u^2 + 2B uv + C v^2) + (2Ax_0 + 2 B y_0) u + (2Bx_0 + 2 C y_0) v + (Ax_0^2 + 2B x_0 y_0 + C y_0^2)  $$
$$ 2 D x + 2 E y + F = 2 D u + 2 E v + 2 D x_0 + 2 E y_0 + F $$
In the original $A x^2 + 2 B xy + C y^2 + 2 D x + 2 E y + F,$ the quadratic terms come out to $A u^2 + 2B uv + C v^2,$ as was guaranteed to happen for the highest degree terms. Next, we get
$ (2Ax_0 + 2 B y_0 + 2 D)u,  $ so that the coefficient of the linear term $u$ is actually $0.$ 
Also, $ (2Bx_0 + 2 C y_0 + 2 E)v ,  $ so that the coefficient of the linear term $u$ is actually $0.$
The constant term comes out to
$$ Ax_0^2 + 2B x_0 y_0 + C y_0^2 + 2 D x_0 + 2 E y_0 + F  $$
to which we say, Why Not?
The whole thing is now
$$  A u^2 + 2B uv + C v^2 + ( Ax_0^2 + 2B x_0 y_0 + C y_0^2 + 2 D x_0 + 2 E y_0 + F)  = 0, $$
where the thing in parentheses is a constant. Let us give the constant a name, $ W = ( Ax_0^2 + 2B x_0 y_0 + C y_0^2 + 2 D x_0 + 2 E y_0 + F).  $ So we get
$$   A u^2 + 2B uv + C v^2 + W = 0 $$

Comment: I guess I would add the motivation of completing the square. If we've rotated coordinates to get rid of the cross term, then we have $$A(x-D/A)^2+C(y-E/C)^2 +\dots = 0,$$ and perhaps this explains where your system of linear equations comes from.

Comment: @TedShifrin, hi. I'll think about putting it in, although my first impression was that the translation part was asked about, how to cancel the linear terms. For me, a quadratic form has become a central object after some twenty years of them; I admit students may not feel the same way. As far as diagonalization, I tend to emphasize the non-orthogonal Hermite type manipulations for quadratic forms, which sticks with integers if the original coefficients are integers, just successive completing squares after multiplying by any necessary factors.

Comment: It's funny.  Nobody asks for "motivation" for completing the square when we write an axis-aligned parabola as (y-y0) = a (x- x0)^2.  I like that your answer resists the impetus of the question toward introducing mystery where there is none.  If the properties of the conic have been barfed out into a mass of x's and y's for algebraic convenience, let us not at least pretend there is a mystery about how to shift coordinates and eliminate x and y.   Might be nice to add a bit showing that this will fail if the conic has no center.  Which doesn't prevent us from, say, using vertex coordinates...

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of sounding grumpy, *I don't unless I have to*.

I try to write my conic sections in the closest form to a description of its properties I can get away with.  I don't try to understand conic properties as a result of cartesian coordinates, because that's backward.   I *do* keep track of what methods are necessary to distinguish and retrieve properties from a faceless abstraction like homogeneous coordinates, so that I can spend as little time as possible working backward.

The cartesian form is unsuitable for many common tasks such as anything that requires an oriented figure.  It's clumsy for moving, rigid figures.  I prefer a form I can read, that doesn't lose track of the properties in the first place.

Consider at least one alternative.  Following Apollonius, we can always write (one branch of) a conic section in the form

${\bf \vec f}(t) =P + t \sqrt{c_1 + c_2 t^2}\, {\bf \vec x} +t^2 {\bf \vec y}$

where P is any point on the section, **x** is tangent to the curve at P (the ordinate direction), and **y** gives the diameter direction. We may choose any lengths and directions for the vectors. Specifically, we define the conic by choosing *any ordinate chord to the diameter with base point P*.

I leave it to you to identify
1. why this is so, and to explain
2. why it is equivalent to the general second-order Bezier section (conic section from two points, the intersection of the tangents at those points, and a free parameter, $ 0<\lambda <1$ indicating the elevation of the curve above the base of the triangle.)
3. the relationship between c1, c2, and $ \lambda$.  (Hint: the shape of a conic section is a single parameter).
4. the center of the section, if any.
5. the (major) axis.

hehehe.
Just kidding. Friends don't leave friends alone with abstractions.  If you want to know, I can tell you *how I have gone about the construction* until you are satisfied.   We have got the wrong side of an abstraction when we get to asking "why?" from the blind end of the puzzle instead of examining *whether and how* measure is preserved by the construction of the abstraction in the first place.  To do this, we must have an independent reference.  Here, it is the figures themselves.  Suppose, for example, we knew nothing about conic sections.  How would you describe the relationship of the standard form to the act of measuring distances and directions on the surface of a flat cut through a cone?

Hmmmm?