# Cone ellipse intersection

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

> Given the cone $K=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3 :x^2+y^2-z^2=0\}$
>   and the equation of $E=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3 :z=my+c\}$
>   
>   Find an equation for the intersecion of the cone and the plane

The intersection is obviously $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R : x^2+y^2-(my+c)^2,z=my+c\}$
I got a little confused by the problem. Is it possible to find an equation $f(x,y,z)=0$ that describes the given ellipse ? ($f \in \mathbb R$)

If thats not possible how would one parameterize the given equation ?

Would appreciate your help

Comment: It’s only an ellipse if $m^2\lt1$. When $m^2\gt1$ you get a hyperbola instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let

$$f(x,y,z)=\left\| x^2+y^2-z^2\right\|^2+\left\| z-my-c\right\|^2$$

Comment: Thanks.I Feel pretty dumb for not figuring that out xD

Comment: What does `||...||^2` mean in this case?

Comment: The square of norm.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $m^2\lt1$ so that you actually have an ellipse, the answers to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2094905/265466) give you everything you need for a parameterization of it. If you have the center $\mathbf p$, the unit direction vectors of the major and minor axes $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ and the semi-axis lengths $a$ and $b$, then the ellipse can be parameterized as $\mathbf p + a\cos t\,\mathbf v+b\sin t\,\mathbf w$.