# Finding the vertex of the parabola $x^2+4xy+4y^2+2y+2x+75=0$ using differentiation

Tags: derivatives, conic-sections

> So my math teacher in school just gave me the equation of a parabola: 
>   $$x^2+4xy+4y^2+2y+2x+75=0$$
>   I am asked to find its vertex using differentiation and not using any vertex form or anything like that. How do I do that?

Comment: Hint: Use partial derivatives.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what you’ve studied. One possibility is to find where the curvature is maximized. Another possibility is to find a point at which the normal line to the curve only intersects it at that point.

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941210/why-does-partial-differentiation-give-centre-of-a-conic

Answer (score 0):

Particular procedure when given $f = x^2+4xy+4y^2+2y+2x+75 = 0$

$$
f_x = 2x+4y+2 =0\\
f_y = 4x+8y+2 = 0
$$

represent parallel lines. The parabola symmetry axis has the same gradient so defining now

$$
l\to -4x+2y-\lambda
$$

which is perpendicular to $f_x, f_y$ the next step is to determine $\lambda$ imposing that $l$ is tangent do $f=0$ so substituting $y = \frac 12(4x-\lambda)$ into $f=0$ and solving for $x$ we get

$$
x = \frac{1}{25}\left(5\lambda-3\pm\sqrt{-1866-5\lambda}\right)
$$

At tangency, $x$ is unique so $-1866-5\lambda = 0$ giving $\lambda = -\frac{1866}{5}$ and one of the tangents is

$$
l = -4x+2y-\frac{1866}{5}=0
$$

[image]

The vertex determination follows.

$$
x^* = -\frac{1869}{25},\ \ y^* = \frac{927}{25}
$$

Comment: thank you very much that really helped me a lot :)