# Finding a centre of a curve

Tags: analytic-geometry

So, what I need is not any construction, but equations. You are given the curve as: $p: ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$ and I need formulas for finding its center. I think it is something like $p_x^2+p_y^2=0$ but I am not sure. Thanks!

Comment: See this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286146/how-to-find-center-of-a-conic-section-from-the-equation

Comment: It is a conical section ; remind the particular case of a parabola, which has no center.