# Translating an ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, 3d

I have the equation of an ellipsoid of the form: $ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 + 2fyz + 2gxz + 2hxy + 2px + 2qy +2rz + d = 0$

How does one translate the ellipsoid given above to the origin and have the equation of the form?: $ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 + 2fyz + 2gxz + 2hxy = 1$

[image]
[image]

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286146/how-to-find-center-of-a-conic-section-from-the-equation?noredirect=1&lq=1) for finding the center of an ellipse from its general equation. After that, it’s just a matter of substitution. One of the answers in fact goes through this transformation in detail. The methods have obvious extensions to higher-dimensional quadrics.

Comment: Note, by the way, that to get a $1$ on the right-hand side, you’re likely going to have to rescale the equation after translation. In particular, the remaining coefficients will _not_ be the same ones that you started with. In the illustration that you added, it looks like you’ve simply deleted the linear terms and set the constant term to $-1$ without making the appropriate adjustments to the remaining coefficients, which is why the two ellipses in your diagram are different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Solving the linear equations from the three partial derivatives, and substituting

$x\mapsto x + (b (g r - c p) + c h q + f^2 p - f (g q + h r))/(a b c - a f^2 - b g^2 - c h^2 + 2 f g h) $
$y\mapsto y + (-a c q + a f r + c h p - f g p + g^2 q - g h r)/(a b c - a f^2 - b g^2 - c h^2 + 2 f g h)$
$z\mapsto z + (-a b r + a f q + b g p - f h p - g h q + h^2 r)/(a b c - a f^2 - b g^2 - c h^2 + 2 f g h) $

yields the constant term $\frac{a\,b\,c\,d-a\,d\,f^{2}-b\,d\,g^{2}+2\,d\,f\,g\,h-c\,d\,h^{2}-b\,c\,p^{2}+f^{
      2}p^{2}-2\,f\,g\,p\,q+2\,c\,h\,p\,q-a\,c\,q^{2}+g^{2}q^{2}+2\,b\,g\,p\,r-2\,f\,h\,p\,r+2\,a\,f
      \,q\,r-2\,g\,h\,q\,r-a\,b\,r^{2}+h^{2}r^{2}}{a\,b\,c-a\,f^{2}-b\,g^{2}+2\,f\,g\,h-c\,h^{2}}$ which can be set to $-1$ by a scaling factor.

Comment: A simpler way, I think, to characterize the constant term after translation is that it’s equal to the result of substituting the center coordinates into the left-hand side of the original equation.