# Product of equation of two lines

Tags: analytic-geometry

Why does the product of equations of straight lines represents 2 straight lines?
Why does a 2nd degree equation is so linear?

Comment: $(ax+by+c)(a'x+b'y+c')=0 \iff \begin{cases}ax+by+c=0 \ \text{OR} \\a'x+b'y+c'=0\end{cases}$ ; the logical "OR" connective is very important because it is in connection whith the set connective "union", that's all : you have the union of two straight lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the language of conics,

\begin{align}
  0 &= (ax+by+c)(a'x+b'y+c') \\[10pt]
  \iff 0 &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    x & y & 1
   \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix}
     aa' & \frac{ab'+a'b}{2} & \frac{ac'+a'c}{2} \\
     \frac{ab'+a'b}{2} & bb' & \frac{bc'+b'c}{2} \\
     \frac{ac'+a'c}{2} & \frac{bc'+b'c}{2} & cc'
   \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix}
    x \\ y \\ 1
   \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Note that

$$\det
\begin{pmatrix}
  aa' & \frac{ab'+a'b}{2} \\
  \frac{ab'+a'b}{2} & bb'
\end{pmatrix}
=-\frac{(ab'-a'b)^2}{4}<0$$

providing non-parallel and

$$\det
\begin{pmatrix}
  aa' & \frac{ab'+a'b}{2} & \frac{ac'+a'c}{2} \\
  \frac{ab'+a'b}{2} & bb' & \frac{bc'+b'c}{2} \\
  \frac{ac'+a'c}{2} & \frac{bc'+b'c}{2} & cc'
\end{pmatrix}
=0$$

implying a pair of straight lines.

> It's a special case that the section plane cutting the radiant point of the cones.

[image]

See another answer [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898005/finding-the-asymptotes-of-a-general-hyperbola/2670187#2670187) for your interest.