# Calculating the asymptotes of an hyperbola from the general equation

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, education

Suppose that the conditions which ensure that the following equation is an hyperbola are verified:

$$ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dx+2ey+f=0$$

What are the general expressions of the two asymptotes of the hyperbola?

---

EDIT

I tried to follow the procedure [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898005/finding-the-asymptotes-of-a-general-hyperbola), but I get (I assumed all the coefficient greater than zero; if I did not give a sign to the coefficients, I cannot solve the limit):

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} y(x) - mx = $$

$$ = \lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} \frac{-E- Cx + \sqrt{(E + Cx)^2 - 4B(Dx + F)}}{2B} - \frac{2A}{C}x = - \infty$$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: See also the other answer of the duplicate question.

Comment: Hello @Aretino, the answer of Ng Chung Tak?

Comment: Yes, exactly: that's simpler to use.

Comment: @Aretino Please see my comment to Ng Chung Tak.